# RecyclerView: Async image-loading

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

Im using `RecyclerView` to display a list containing an `imageView`. To make the UI more fluently, I load 58dp thumbnails saved on sd card into these imageViews with an `asyncTask`.

The problem is, that once a `childView` comes in visual display, an old image from another data is being reused and then replaced once the `AsyncTask` finishes. I can stop the shuffling by setting the `imageView` bitmap to null in `onPreExecute`.

Is there a way to really reuse old images or do I really have to load the images from sd-card each time a new `View` comes in place? This makes view quite ugly because either there are wrong images first or the image is plain white.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Due to view reuse you'll fetch views with content already on them, this was a problem on `ListViews` too if you were using the `ViewHolder` pattern, which you should.

There are two solutions here, the good practice and the bad hack:

- In the good practice you set your `ImageView` to display nothing at the
  beginning of `bindViewHolder(VH holder, int position)` using
  `setDrawable(null)` or similar.
- In the bad hack you wouldn't recycle/reuse views, not enforcing the `ViewHolder` pattern, and you'd inflate it every time, but that's only allowed in `ListView` and other old components.

Comment: So the old bitmaps attached to the views are beeing discarded once they leave the screen?

Comment: You can put them in a LruCache when you read them or before removing them, and refetch them later.

Comment: Initiate the `ImageView` or you have to use `setDrawable(null)`?

Comment: Not works I tried with  setDrawable / setBitmap = null not works

Comment: Not working, even more `setBitmap(null)` delays the shuffling but at the end its the problem persists

Answer (score 8):

You should check the [universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).
It has memory cache, disk cache and it loads your images asynchronously so doesn't block the ui. You can set default image and/or failed to fetch image etc. It can sample down your image to decrease the memory footprint of the bitmap. I really recommend you to use it for images.

Do not disable recyclable for your case because it is pointless. Images must be recycled because their bitmap drawables generate very high memory overload if not properly sampled.

Sample usage in RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    String imageUri = "";//local or remote image uri address
    //viewHolder.imgView: reference to your imageview
    //before you call the displayImage you have to 
    //initialize imageloader in anywhere in your code for once.   
    //(Generally done in the Application class extender.)
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, viewHolder.imgView);
}
```

edit:
Nowadays, I consider Glide as my main image loading and caching library.
 You can use it like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUri)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.myplaceholder)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: why Glide why not using Picasso ? any advantage ?

Comment: Picasso is better +1

Comment: @mhdjazmati That depends on the requirement... Glide supports Animated GIF and thumbnails (good for list views).

Answer (score 5):

You should cancel the old request before starting a new one, but regardless of cancelling you can still show the wrong image if both images loaded more or less at the same time on the same container/view holder that has been recycled (happens easily with fast scroll and small images).

The solution is to:

1. Store some unique identifier in the View Holder during onBindViewHolder (this happens synchronously so if VH is recycled this will be overwritten)
2. Then load the image asynchronously (with AsynchTask, RxJava, etc) and pass this unique id in the async call for reference
3. Finally, in the image loaded method for post-processing (onPostExecute for AsyncTasks), check that the id passed in the async request is the same as the current id present in the View Holder.

Example loading icons from apps in background with RxJava:

```
 public void loadIcon(final ImageView appIconView, final ApplicationInfo appInfo, final String uniqueAppID) {
    Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            return appIconView.getContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
        })
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe( drawable -> {
                 if (uniqueAppID.equals(mUniqueAppID)) { // Show always the correct app icon
                    appIconView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                 }
             }
         );
}
```

Here mUniqueAppID is a field of the view holder changed by onBindViewHolder

Comment: If the id is not the same then imageview drawable remains blank, what should we do in this situation?

Comment: @Duna that's correct, if the id is not the same it means the viewHolder was recycled and the drawable is not the correct one for this view. The async load with a correct id should eventually happen. If view remains blank it might mean the async image loading (before id check) just failed.

Comment: I got your point of view, but lets say we have 10 items visible, for each one onBindView is called. The loading of each image takes 1 second but the `mUniqueAppID`is already set to the latest item(1 second not passed) -> then only the last image will be shown

Comment: @Duna I see the misunderstanding, the `mUniqueAppID` is a field in the ViewHolder, same as the views referenced in the ViewHolder, so as long as the view is not recycled, there will be 1 `mUniqueAppID` per viewHolder

Answer (score 1):

you must cancel old request in "onBindViewHolder" method:

```
try{
        ((SpecialOfferViewHolder)viewHolder).imageContainer.cancelRequest();
}catch(Exception e) {

}
```

remember to save image container in the viewHolder:

```
public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                ((SpecialOfferViewHolder)viewHolder).imageContainer=response;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). 
**A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android.**
Easy to use and a powerful library. Using this library you can fetch images asynchronously or synchronously from Resources, assets, files, content providers.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the good practice:

> In the good practice you set your ImageView to display nothing at the beginning of bindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) using setDrawable(null) or similar.

not to display nothing, but to display a loader image so to give the user a feedback that theres some processing going on in that view and in a little while it will see the results. Seeing just a blank view is not good practice, you need to give feedback to the user.

Answer (score -2):

What MLProgrammer says is quite correct.

The solution, fortunately, it's easy: stop the recycling

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

---

This choice has its consequences, since doing what I suggest above inhibits one of RecyclerView main purposes: recycling.

- Your RecyclerView will be slower to scroll (a new Holder has to be created every time, inflating again from the resources);
- your usage of memory will be bigger.

Comment: If you're suggesting this solution at least mention the consequences, because it's a bad practice.