# Loading picture to correct position in recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, universal-image-loader

I make a network call in my recycler adapter to retrieve the url for a picture. After the url is received, I use universal image loader to load the picture into an image view. The problem is when I don't scroll the pictures are loaded into the right place but as soon as I scroll the pictures are inflated in the wrong place.
Here's my adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder is ViewHolder) {
        val article = feeds[position]

        holder.articleTitle.setFont("SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf")
        holder.articleDescription.setFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf")
        holder.articleTime.setFont("OpenSans-Light.ttf")

        mAnimator?.onBindViewHolder(holder.itemView, position)
        holder.apply {
            article.apply {
                articleTitle.text = title
                articleDescription.text = Html.fromHtml(description)
                articleTime.text = TimeUtils.convertLongToTime(pubDate)

                if (image.isBlank()){
                    //load picture url when it's empty
                    mContext?.doAsync {
                        ImageExtractor.extractImageUrl(link, object : OnImageExtractorListener {
                            override fun onSuccess(url: String) {
                                v("imaaaage success $title $url")
                                mContext?.runOnUiThread {
                                    article.image = url

                                    //use uil to load the image didn't work so I tried just updating the model
                                    //articleImage.displayImage(url)

                                    feeds[position] = article
                                    notifyItemChanged(position)
                                }
                                val dbo = context.getDatabase()
                                dbo.updateArticleImage(dbo,url,article.id)
                            }

                            override fun onError() {
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }else{
                    articleImage.displayImage(image)
                    isRead?.let {
                        if (isRead!! && !isSaved){
                            grayScale(holder)
                        }
                    }
                }

                container.setOnClickListener {
                    itemClick(this)
                    if (!isSaved){
                        article.isRead = true
                        feeds[position] = article
                        notifyItemChanged(position)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else if (holder is LoadingViewHolder){
        holder.progressBar.isIndeterminate = true
    }
}
```

I need a way to load the images in their right places if the user is scrolling or not.

Comment: Try to use any image loader library like glide, fresco etc. and also maintain your image url with your viewholder

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525999/recyclerview-async-image-loading

Comment: @ArbazRizvi I'll try another library and see but i'm currently using [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a library for async image loading, e.g. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). There everything is handled for you, like caching, placeholder ...

In your adapter:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("url")
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder).into(imageView);
```

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

you nedd to put setHasStableIds(true); in your Adapter's constructor and put :

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

So it will keep all images at exact positions even after scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The RecyclerView will reuse ViewHolders to reduce inflation and memory usage.

The correct way is in the onBindViewHolder is to clear the old state of the View (seting image as null) and seting the new ones.

Make sure to clear it all times it come onBind (before testing)

```
articleImage.displayImage(null)
if (image.isBlank()){
```

Since downloading is a async task it will not be at the way when binding, that's why you just clear the old one, for texts it is immediately available to be set.

Comment: setImageBitmap(null) before downloading the new one

Comment: Thanks will try it out and see